# What’s this concept called?

Tags: halacha-theory, tzitzis, shulchan-aruch

Looking at Shulchan Aruch earlier surrounding the laws of making tzitzit, who can make them, who can’t make them etc etc

One of the points was that a non observant Jew or a non Gd fearing Jew would make the mitzvah of making tzitzit invalid and not kosher. Subsequently that goes for a non Jew too.

Now, I’ve read before different times that an observant Jew should not be using sacred items or should not obtain said items like tzitzit from non-observant or non-Gd fearing Jews (as well as non Jews). Does this concept or point have any legal name and is there anywhere where this idea is specifically or formally discussed?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dan and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I don't know about philosophical or metaphysical motives, but halachically, I believe that this is true for anything that requires kavvanah (proper intent) to be kosher. One cannot rely on someone who didn't buy into the system to have kavvanah when making tzitzis.